# Physical Interpretation of Negative Kinetic energy in Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Suppose we have a 1-D finite potential well:

$V(x) = 0; |x| > a $

$V(x) = -U_0; |x|\leq a$

Suppose the particle is in a bound stationary state. Then, there is a finite probability that the particle is found outside the finite well since there is an exponentially decaying tail of the (spatial) wavefunction extending to $ \pm \infty$.

Now, the energy of the particle is $E = -E_0$ where $|E_0| < |U_0|$

Since there is a finite probability of the particle to exist outside the potential well where potential energy of the particle is $ 0 (>- E_0)$. In the exponential decay part, the Kinetic energy is negative.

**In fact, in any case, whenever $\psi '' (x) > 0$ we have kinetic energy to be negative.**

Is there any physical interpretation of negative kinetic energy ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *physical* meaning is you're in the classically forbidden region, accessible only by quantum tunnelling. The basic idea, as you've calculated, is a wavefunction scaling as $\exp(-kx)$ rather than $\exp(ikx)$, so it's exponentially unlikely you'll get a very negative KE. (See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_tunnelling#The_WKB_approximation) for further details, in a more general setting than the well you describe.) That's unsurprising, since classical mechanics needs to remain approximately true.

Answer (score 2):

The Hamiltonian with potential, $$H=K+V$$ does not commute with the kinetic energy operator, $K$. Thus, the *classical* intuition based on adding the kinetic and the potential energies is misleading (particularly, adding them at specific space points). One can however calculate the mean kinetic energy and its variance. One could also verify the energy conservation within the Framework of the [Ehrenfest theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ehrenfest_theorem): $$\langle H\rangle = \langle K\rangle + \langle V\rangle.$$